# app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac error while running radle for unit test in AndroiStudio using windows OS

Tags: gradle

> C:\Users\SINE90\AndroidStudioProjects\MyfirstTest>gradlew connectAndroidTest
>   :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:validateDebugSigning
>   :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac
>   C:\Users\SINE90\AndroidStudioProjects\MyfirstTest\app\src\androidTest\java\com\example\sine90\myfirsttest\ApplicationTest.java:10: error: class ApplicationTest clashes wi
>   th package of same name
>   public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase {
>          ^
>   C:\Users\SINE90\AndroidStudioProjects\MyfirstTest\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\androidTest\debug\com\example\sine90\myfirsttest\ApplicationTest\BuildConfig.java
>   :4: error: package com.example.sine90.myfirsttest.ApplicationTest clashes with class of same name
>   package com.example.sine90.myfirsttest.ApplicationTest;
>   ^
>   2 errors
>   :app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 36.495 secs

Comment: Did you find the solution to it ?